# Reading file in java on Mac

Tags: java, macos, filereader

I am doing a tutorial on java and the video I am at now deals with FileReading, but it is for windows and I am on a mac. Please help

```js
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  String fileName = "/Users/--MyUsername--/Desktop/test.rtf";
  
  File textFile = new File(fileName);
  
  Scanner in = new Scanner(textFile);
  
  int value = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Read value: " + value);
  
  in.nextLine();
  
  int count = 2;
  
  while(in.hasNextLine()){
   String line = in.nextLine();
   
   System.out.println(count + ": " + line);
   count++;
  }
  
  in.close();
 }

}
```

and this is the error that I am getting

```js
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
 at L37ReadingTextFiles.App.main(App.java:17)
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read integers from the file, but the content is not integer, please use  `String value = in.next();` instead of `int value = in.nextInt();`

Comment: This one was correct, but it was also because the file trying to be read was .rtf and not .txt . thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with the .rtf file. There might be a way to get that type of file to work as expected in java, but for a beginner, I would recommend making it a .txt file.

Comment: Thank you for your help, part of the reason was because the file was not a .txt file